# How to create a dll/exe on the fly in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection

I know I can spawn new process using compiled exe file.

Suppose I have a class with a method in my app which I want to be run in the separate process.

Can I compile this method into separate assembly in **run-time** and spawn process running this newly created file?

Comment: do you have the code of the metod as a string ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure... look at `CSharpCodeProvider` that can read and compile code to e.g. an .exe file

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx

Comment: yes that what i was looking for. i just forgot the name of the class! :))) thank you

Answer (score 1):

Why not just run in its own App Domain. Gives process like separation.

Comment: i need windows process not .net app domain.

Comment: They want to compile Kenny! Compilers!

Comment: That's especially important if you plan on doing lots of compilations during runtime. I learned it the hard way that you cannot unload an assembly, except when being placed in a separate application domain.